# istio docker-compose example

Tags: docker, docker-compose, istio, api-gateway

I am looking for a standalone `istio` docker-compose example.

Something like what `ambassador` does https://www.getambassador.io/user-guide/docker-compose (their `- ./config:/ambassador/ambassador-config`
 trick is very handy to be able to change the config locally)

All I could find was this but it relies on consul, which I do not plan to use:
https://istio.io/docs/setup/consul/quick-start/

Ultimately I am looking for something that allows me to experiment locally with a [Gateway](https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/istio.networking.v1alpha3/#Gateway).